# Main dataset is getting modified when local dataset is modified

Tags: c#, datatables, dataset, windows

Below is my code.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = dsComplaints;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ds.Tables[0];
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr.ItemArray = new object[] {"--Select Complaint--" };
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
```

dsComplaints is globally declared which has the main data. I am copying it to a local DataSet ds. Then I assign the table from ds to a datatable. I am adding a row(select complaint) in data table. But when the insertion happens, my main dataset i.e. dsComplaints is also added with a row. How can i avoid that. I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) method to create a new copy of same `DataSet` instead of using the reference only of the original one to avoid this :

```
DataSet ds = dsComplaints.Copy();
```

From **MSDN DOCS** this is what `Copy` does:

> Copies both the structure and data for this DataSet.

Now you can do whatever is needed with the copy and it would not effect the original version of DataSet.